# Where are the TrueCrypt logs located in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, truecrypt

I have tried many configurations and different pen drives.
I am using TrueCrypt 7.1a.

It always starts formating and then freezes the whole system, I have to forcibly restar my computer.

Where should I look at to have more information on why it is happening?

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: added tags to info the os

Comment: Have you checked /var/logs?

Comment: I see nothing different there.